# Linear programming with a convergent coefficient

Tags: limits-and-convergence, linear-programming

The following linear programming problem 
$x_n = \arg\min c_n'x  \mbox{ subject to } Ax<b$
has a changing coefficient $c_n$. We have that $c_n\rightarrow c_*$. What happens to the solution $x_n$? Does it converge to $x_*$, the optimal solution with coefficient $x_*$?

Comment: We can assume that the $x_n$ is unique for all $c_n$.

Comment: It may jump around. Let the restrictions be $x,y\ge 0,x+y\le 1$. Now let $c_n$ be $(1,1+(-1)^n/n)$. However, if it does converge, it converges to *an* optimal solution for the limit problem.

Comment: I think the last sentence should be "...with coefficient $c_*$."

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Yes, you are correct.